# How to test for booleans in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to test in JS if a variable is a boolean or not. It has four possible value TRUE, FALSE, "TRUE" and "FALSE".
I am using the following code but the thing is that it never goes to the else even if the "value" is some other string.

```js
let value = "true";// could be true, false, "true", "false" or some other text string
if ($.type(new Boolean(value)) === "boolean") {
  $("input[value='" + value + "']").prop("checked", true);
} else {
  $("input[name=" + columnName + "]").val(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not clear how you expect this to work. Broken code is not a good substitute for a proper explanation of expected behavior. Providing relevant html would also help as per [mcve]

Comment: Remember that Boolean("false") == true. True story...

Answer (score 0):

You just need the `typeof` keyword:

```js
let value = "true"; // could be true, false, "true", "false" or some other text string
var columnName = "";
if (typeof value === "boolean") {
  // $("input[value='" + value + "']").prop("checked", true);
  console.log("Yes");
} else {
  // $("input[name=" + columnName + "]").val(value);
  console.log("No");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now the reason why it doesn't go is, it is stored as string. The `typeof` or whatever way it is, will report it as `string` and not `boolean`. You shouldn't use `"` quotes to represent boolean variables.

To achieve what you need, you need a condition like:

```
if (typeof value === "boolean" || value.toLowerCase() === "true" || value.toLowerCase() === "false")
```

This will make it work for you.

Comment: i think what the op want is more likely to be `typeof value === "boolean" || value === "true" || value === "false"`

Comment: @UlysseBN Check now?

Comment: let value = "true"; If you do typeof(value) will give you string not boolean.

Comment: @PraveenKumar i'm not op

Comment: @Shiladitya What did I explain in the whole answer then? See *Now the reason why it doesn't go is, it is stored as string. The `typeof` or whatever way it is, will report it as `string` and not `boolean`. You shouldn't use `"` quotes to represent boolean variables.*

Comment: @UlysseBN Sorry mate... I know your aren't the OP. Do you feel that the answer is better now with your recommendation being added in it.